# Error using anchor tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, anchor

```
  var titleLink=document.createElement("a");
  titleLink.setAttribute("href",'answers[3][i]');
  titleLink.innerHTML=answers[1][i];  

  newDiv.appendChild(titleLink);
```

When I click on the link when created through js, it shows page not found. But the same link when I add it explicitly using `<a>` tag in html opens correctly. What could be the problem??

Link to the entire code is here: http://codepen.io/jpninanjohn/pen/GZrzoG

Comment: `titleLink.setAttribute("href",answers[3][i]);`, remove the quotes of `answers..`

Comment: That string is unlikely to be the `href`, try removing the quotes `answers[3][i]`. Also try using the console to debug: `console.log(titleLink.href)`.

Comment: As said, you are setting the href attribute with a string instead of the array position http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOpggx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is an exercise of FreeCodeCamp. As a FreeCodeCamper, it is nice to see another camper asking question in stackoverflow.

Anyway, 
you are almost near to the solution! Just make this tweak and you are good to go!

```
titleLink.setAttribute("target","_blank");
titleLink.setAttribute("href",answers[3][i]);
titleLink.innerHTML=answers[1][i];
```

It was a **typo** that you added single quotation over **answers[3][i]**.
Optionally, I added an attribute to open the link in a new tab.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes around answer:

```
  var titleLink=document.createElement("a");
  titleLink.setAttribute("href",answers[3][i]);
  titleLink.innerHTML=answers[1][i];  

  newDiv.appendChild(titleLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error in you code, you pass 'answers[3][i]' as a string. Try without brackets )